# Is it possible to export LinkedIn contacts with city and state?

Tags: linkedin, contacts

I'm following the [directions to export LinkedIn contacts](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3) and it does work, but the resulting export file has blank values for most of the fields, including city and state.  Is there a way to export that does include this information?

Answer (score 1):

No. You are getting all the possible data now. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

As a recruiter, I've been trying to find an answer for this for years. There was at one point a way to do this with a LinkedIn API token but LinkedIn blocked this functionality in 2015.  LinkedIn will never download the locations with the candidates and doing it manually would take 80+ hours of manual entry.

Here at Moonlight we worked on this problem for over a year and thoroughly searched for a company or software that can do this. To our knowledge, there is no one that can do this

Moonlight Strategic Search has developed a way to take any LinkedIn excel contacts file and fill out the locations of the people. You can order the service here:

http://www.moonlightstrategicsearch.com/linkedin-data-locations/

Comment: I'm still not enthralled with this answer, either.   While you disclose your affiliation with the product, this answer seems to exist solely to promote your service.  The question is asking how to export *from* LinkedIn with that information intact.

Comment: @Logan: are you saying that your service does some localization work unrelated to LinkedIn?

Comment: Once you have the company name you can just do a lookup on Google Places API and throw out any with multiple matches (uncertain location).